# Code=-997 “Lost connection to background transfer service”

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6

I have a app making thousands of API Calls giving me JSON data which i save it in coredata using NSURLSession with BackgroundConfiguration..
It works fine , but for certain downloads it gives me [code=-1 "unknown error"] followed by [ Code=-997 "Lost connection to background transfer service" ] errors.
I have searched the web for possible solutions but couldn't figure out a solution yet.

Answer (score 4):

Try to check device logs. You could find crashes of Background Transfer daemon. I found that it may crash if the daemon exceeds 40MB memory limit.

Comment: what if the file to download is more than 40MB and any clue how to clear the memory for `NSURLSession`

Comment: It is not a problem in general (because in general you download and upload directly to/from file) case but a problem in case when you upload NSData object via download task.

Comment: ok i am writing to files ..but number of files is too many.. i have seen from the tests that if i schedule more than 800 files  it starts giving this error

Comment: Interesting, probably you need to decrease files count somehow, e.g. download them by pack of N files

Answer (score 0):

Its just a bug. Upgrade your sdk version. It was solved in GM. :)

[See this thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1031240#1031240).

Comment: But this relates to Extenstions , but i dont have any extensions in my app and also i have the latest xcode 6.1.1

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue where i am trying to download 1000+ images in background and i can only get around 50 of them downloaded, for rest it says 
"Lost connection to background transfer service"

I am using xcode 6.1 SDK 8.1 on iOS 8.1.2 & 8.1.3